# MySQL Exact syntax for this Query : Finding nearby Location

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, geo

below is a Query for finding **products** nearby from user's lat, lon and Radius..

I want this function to just **Return the ID** of the store... The query doesnt seem to work however

```
SELECT
                   product_id

                FROM
                    sm_products
                WHERE
                    ROUND(
                        $earthRadius * ACOS(  
                            SIN( $userlat*PI()/180 ) * SIN( geo_lat*PI()/180 )
                            + COS( $userlat*PI()/180 ) * COS( geo_lat*PI()/180 )  *  COS( (geo_lon*PI()/180) - ($userlon*PI()/180) )   ) 
                    , 1) AS distance <= $userRadius
                ORDER BY
                    distance ASC
```

The below Query which is working.. but id does return both ID and distance which i dont need... I just need to return the `product_id` within radius

```
SELECT
                ROUND(
                    $earthRadius * ACOS(  
                        SIN( $userlat*PI()/180 ) * SIN( geo_lat*PI()/180 )
                        + COS( $userlat*PI()/180 ) * COS( geo_lat*PI()/180 )  *  COS( (geo_lon*PI()/180) - ($userlon*PI()/180) )   ) 
                , 1)
                AS distance,
                product_id

            FROM
                sm_products
            HAVING
                distance <= $userRadius    
            ORDER BY
                distance ASC
```

Any Help?

EDIT (Function Call)

```
$params['product_id'] = $this->productsInRadius($userlat, $userlon, $radius);
```

Comment: why does it matter if the query returns both? Simply ignore that field when processing the data

Comment: @RamRaider : I have added the function call to Question.. how can i retrieve only the selected field..

Comment: The query doesn't work? What happens? An error? An empty result set?

Comment: @JonStirling : It returns an error 'check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near AS'

Comment: @SharanMohandas Then the problem is probably `AS distance` which I don't _think_ is valid inside a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @JonStirling : any idea on how to rewrite the Query so it returns only `product_id` after required condition check

Comment: Whether this is the best way, I don't know, but what you could do is shift the where condition calculation into the SELECT with the alias, then update the where to check the alias against your variable. Finally, wrap the lot in another SELECT query that just returns product id using the updated current SQL as a subselect and apply the order to that.

Answer (score 0):

@JonStirling This Query works... But I'm not sure whether its a good Practice

```
SELECT
                    product_id
                FROM
                    sm_products
                WHERE
                    ROUND(
                        $earthRadius * ACOS(  
                            SIN( $userlat*PI()/180 ) * SIN( geo_lat*PI()/180 )
                            + COS( $userlat*PI()/180 ) * COS( geo_lat*PI()/180 )  *  COS( (geo_lon*PI()/180) - ($userlon*PI()/180) )   ) 
                    , 1) <= $userRadius    
                ORDER BY 
                ROUND(
                        $earthRadius * ACOS(  
                            SIN( $userlat*PI()/180 ) * SIN( geo_lat*PI()/180 )
                            + COS( $userlat*PI()/180 ) * COS( geo_lat*PI()/180 )  *  COS( (geo_lon*PI()/180) - ($userlon*PI()/180) )   ) 
                    , 1) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

So I *think* the following should work, but I'm currently unable to test it. If it's wrong, please point it out and I'll drop the answer.

```
SELECT product_id
FROM (
    SELECT
        product_id,
        ROUND(
            $earthRadius * ACOS(SIN( $userlat*PI()/180 ) * SIN(geo_lat*PI()/180 ) + COS( $userlat*PI()/180 ) * COS( geo_lat*PI()/180     ) * COS( (geo_lon*PI()/180) - ($userlon*PI()/180))   
        , 1) AS distance
    FROM
        sm_products
    WHERE
        distance <= $userRadius
)
ORDER BY
   distance ASC;
```

Comment: as i said in the Question... This query works but it does return both id and distance..

Comment: @SharanMohandas The query above would only return `product_id` (if it works at all).

Comment: Though, you could quite easilly get rid of the super-select, return both the product_id and the distance (as in your second example and filter down to the product_id only in your PHP, but you didn't provide any PHP (specifically the `productsInRadius` method) so can't comment on what that would look like.